# Redirection within domain using masking

Tags: php, redirect, subdomain

I want visitors to redirect from a subdomain to another subdomain using masking.

I have a folder **demo** in my root web root **example.com**. when user logs in a subdomain will be created by taking his input name, say **mystore** and he will get **mystore.example.com**. I want him to redirect to demo folder(subdomain) but he should not know this. Even after redirecting he should get **mystore.example.com**.

Is it possible with domain masking? How do I do this and where should I write the code?

Comment: can you show what "redirect using masking" is? can you post your redirect code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that is Subdomain Wildcard and your host must have it enabled and you can create dynamically subdomains using `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/demo/?store_name=%2 [L]
```

This will mean that `mystore.example.com` will actually go to `http://www.example.com/demo/?store_name=mystore`

Comment: Thanks, but will it take the storename from the html form? how i should mention it

Comment: What form? If you have a form just redirect him to `$_POST['storename']` or what name is your input.